The Planet of over a Hundred Moons
What does this abstract picture represent?

Fill the answers to the clues into this grid for the answer:
(Straight lines, standard wordsearch style)

1. Go at train tracks with a shovel (3 2)
2.  Set of tools for cryptographic hash functions? (3 3)
3.  A move in a hive dance? (3 3)
3.  Fluid from the liver (4)
4.  Canadian duct tape guru portrayed by Steve S (3 1)
5.  Plausible name for Delta competitor, were it based out of Carson City (3 2)
6.  Bangkok resident (4)
7.  Nickname you could give a danger-loving dad (2 5)
8.  The story of John Henry, for example (2 4)
9.  Complain (5)
10. Soggy (4)
11. Dressing style often seen at comic conventions (7)
12. The smallest and largest US states (2&2)
13. A single container for holding hair-coloring solution, if you add "of" (4 3 of 3)
13. Formally command flightless bird to drink? ("3 4, 3")
13. Prometheus' first attempt at a name for fire after encountering it? (7 3)
14. Tortoise follower (4)
15. Treasure hoarded by a religious sister? (3 4)
16. Entirely eager(3 4)
16. Guide doc. to target audience (3 2)
17. Name for a ticket in Atlassian tracking system related to a project on human intelligence? (2 4)
18. Lubricant for a cutting tool which was carved from a chest bone? (3 2 3)
19. Terminate computer prog. (3 2)
20. Stare at (4)
21. 18th letter stenciled better than others (5 1)
22. Defers (6)
23. Romanian commune, or name for period associated w/ U.S. soldiers? (5) or (2 3)
24. Self-aware impression given to others (7 3)
25. Plea of rusting robots (6 2)
26. Writer of Psalm 89 (5)
27. "Pester, blot; pick one" ("3 2 3")
28. Lee Airport, MD (3)
29. Headline for news article about a leader of a team of prosecutors who operated a post office (2 3 2)
30. Order from Aladdin that he gets the boat, not his monkey ("1 4, 3")
31. Property of some bland puzzles (2 5)
32. Location of camper at tent area #7 relative to camper at tent area #6 in a campground (2 1 4)
32. Instruction during power outage (3 6)
33. Possible nickname for maid responsible for watching remains of fire? (5 4)

The picture shows ...

 ... SATURN, in more than one way.

The answers ...

 ... are of a varied quality. Some are straightforward, some are quite whimsical and hard to guess.

 Fortunately, there's a big hint in the title: Saturn is the only planet in the solar system with more than a hundred (known) moons. And after solving some clues, one can notice that all answers are anagrams of names of Saturn's moons.

The clues:

  1. DIG RR (Gridr)
  2. SHA KIT (Skathi)
  3. BEE HOP (Phoebe)
  3. BILE (Beli)
  4. RED G (Gerd)
  5. AIR NV (Narvi)
  6. THAI (Hati)
  7. MR RISKY (Skrymir)
  8. RR MYTH (Thrymr)
  9. GRIPE (Greip)
 10. MIRY (Ymir)
 11. COSPLAY (Calypso)
 12. RI & AK (Kari)
 13. SOLE CUP DYE (Polydeuces)
 13. SIP THEE, EMU (Epimetheus)
 13. SUPREME HOT (Prometheus)
 14. HARE (Rhea)
 15. NUN GOLD (Gunnlod)
 16. ALL AVID (Alvaldi)
 16. AIM MS (Mimas)
 17. IQ JIRA (Ijiraq)
 18. RIB AX OIL (Albiorix)
 19. END IO (Dione)
 20. OGLE (Loge)
 21. FINER R (Fenrir)
 22. TABLES (Bestla)
 23. GIERA (Aegir)
 24. MINDFUL AIR (Mundilfari)
 25. REPAIR US (Erriapus)
 26. ETHAN (Anthe)
 27. NAG OR DAB (Angrboda)
 28. ANP (Pan)
 29. DA RAN PO (Pandora)
 30. I RAFT, ABU (Farbauti)
 31. NO THEME (Methone)
 32. UP A SITE (Iapetus)
 32. USE CANDLE (Enceladus)
 33. EMBER GIRL (Bergelmir)

 (Thanks, Stiv, for the Canadian duct tape guru.)

The grid:

 

 The highlighted cells spell SATURN.


Good work. I believe your missing one is this based off this i.e. rot13(ERQ T)

@Stiv: Aha, thanks. Even better work from Amoz, I'd say.

Oops I misspelled that. Updated, but yep great job!

Jnf guvaxvat zvel sbe fbttl ogj, unqa'g urneq bs evzl ohg vg znl jbex gbb

Oh, yes that is a better fit. I just saw my solution, wasn't super convinced, but didn't think of yours. Will fix.

This wordsearch-as-a-crossword is a cool puzzle. A bit tough at times, but you certainly can't say that it has #31. :)
